# PowerShell上でcl.exeを使う

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell

visual studio 2017でPowerShell上でコンパイラを使う方法はありますか?
Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017もありますがPowerShell上ではなくcmd.exe上になってしまいます。

また、Developer Commnd Prompt for VS 2017だとこのメニューから起動しないとcl.exeが使えません。(普通にコマンドプロンプトを起動しただけでは使えない)

普通にPowerShellを起動すれば、いつでもコンパイラを使えるようにしたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

OS: Windows 10 1709

Comment: cmdでpowershellでも`PATH`を通すだけでは？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pscx](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx)モジュールをインストールして`Import-VisualStudioVars`関数を使うのはどうでしょうか？